# Object wrapping vs. Object "pollution" - performance dependent on object size or number?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm rewriting a JavaScript library that I wrote some time ago.
Its purpose is to display an array of objects as a table, that can be sorted, filtered and edited without server communication.

The current solution "pollutes" the objects with additional attributes, that are needed to steer the display.
The original object may look like this

```
{"name":"...","lastname":"...","age":27}
```

And then it has additional attributes like this

```
{"name":"...","lastname":"...","age":27,"TTMDecode":true,"TTMChildren":[]}
```

An alternative Solution may be to only wrap the original object and then work with these wrappers.

```
{"decode":true,"children":[],"data":{"name":"...","lastname":"...","age":27}}
```

**I'm not sure which solution is preferable.**
With the second solution it's easier to return the original object to the server, in the case it was changed, but it doubles the amount of objects for the JavaScript engine.

The solution is able to work with over 20.000 objects and it's fast in current browsers.
But will 40.000 Objects be a problem?

I hope I explained my worries good enough.

Regards

Comment: I am not sure this if question belongs on Stack Overflow. Maybe on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: The number of objects should not limit the performance.

Comment: The overhead should be unnoticeable (to convince yourself - try it!). The rule of thumb is write readable, maintainable code and optimise *if need be*. So unless you have reliable evidence (i.e. proper benchmarks) to suggest intractability, the nested option is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, about your architecture problem: why not make a parent object with the two properties `display` and `data` ? You should not limit your architecture because of performance worries, if it has effect, you will notice it when measuring the performance.

```
var obj = {
    display: {
      // display data
    },
    data: {
      // personal data
    }
);
```

Which implicitly answers the question about the object count, this normally does not matter (if the objects themselves are not huge, it won't affect your performance)

Comment: So this is the same as I suggested. Thank you for all your responses, so I'll wrap it :)

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a design pattern.  You happen to already be using one.

First, you should not pollute a model with things needed just for the view.  This is not the same as saying you can't have convenience methods or computed properties on the model.  A red flag indicating you are doing it wrong is if something specific to your view layer, like DOM, is on the model.    I don't know what `TTMDecode` is in your example...

Second, you are already using design patterns.  You are using **composition** to **decorate** your model objects.

[See this for a description of the Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern),
  [and this for a description of Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

I think you are doing fine.